# Login script for https site

Tags: php, powershell, curl

Is it possible to auto-login to a `https` enabled site by clicking a link?

So far i have tried `php` and `powershell` with no success. Curl does not return anything, the page is just loading with no visible response.

In the good old Days the trick `user:password@www.site.com` worked fine, but now with all the security updates in Explorer this is not allowed.

When accessing my site i get a popup window asking for username and password (looks like iexplorer is creating that popup) so login fields are not in the browser window.

As i said i have tried curl, but how do i know the field names for `username` and `password`?  Do they have standard names? The text in the popup is in Swedish, but it is an English site i am accessing. Therefor i assume the fields have standard names.

Any ideas? preferably an working example :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the user/password of Basic Authorization using `-u` parameter. And for `https` use the `-k` for insecure connection.

```
curl -X POST -L -k
  -u "username:password"
  -d "id=10&name=alex"
  "https://www.example.com/"
```

For other curl parameters check this [curl manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).